# How to switch and do cdk deploy to a different account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I created a project and deployed it to my personal account (678999999999).
My friend David asked me if I can deploy it to his account(123455555555) too.

So I set on my terminal `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` as temporary env variables, and I gave them the values of David's aws account.

When I do `cdk deploy` to David account I get the following error:

```
 ❌ Building assets failed: Error: Building Assets Failed:
Error: Could not assume role in target account 
using current credentials (which are for account 123455555555) User: arn:aws:sts::123455555555:assumed-role/
 AWSReservedSSO_PowerUserAccess_999999999ed47109/moyshe.zuchmir@gmail.com is not authorized 
to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::678999999999:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-678999999999-eu-west-2. 
Please make sure that this role exists in the account. If it doesn't exist, (re)-bootstrap 
the environment with the right '--trust', using the latest version of the CDK CLI.
```

At this point I tried to do `cdk bootstrap` to the project under David's account(as I still have the credentials for David's account in my env variables). The bootstrap seemed to work but when I did CDK deploy later on I got the same error again.

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the `env` prop set for any of your stacks?

Answer (score 0):

You can set multiple AWS profiles .
https://kuchbhilearning.blogspot.com/2022/09/configure-aws-profile.html

For an example :
`aws s3 ls --profile david`

you can use : `yarn cdk deploy --profile david`

Any command that you execute should be followed with profile else it will take the default account/profile